# How to get Jenkins to show on port 8080 with Nginx, Gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, jenkins, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm trying to set up Jenkins so that I can set up a pipeline on [an existing website](https://www.takir.org), but Jenkins does not show up on port 8080.

My project website has been up and running for several months. I'm using Nginx, Gunicorn, Ubuntu 20.04, and Django on an AWS EC2 instance. I'm now trying to set up a pipeline that includes a test/beta environment. This requires Jenkins as per the AWS tutorials. I followed [the example from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-jenkins-with-ssl-using-an-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [this example from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-20-04).

When I try the URL https://theafricankinshipreunion.com:8080/, it says the site cannot be reached. When I try the URL https://theafricankinshipreunion.com (without the port), it takes me to the Unlock Jenkins page. After I enter the password from `sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`, the web browser just goes to a blank page. Looking at the page source, this page is the Setup Wizard[Jenkins] page, but the display is blank.

The results from `sudo systemctl status jenkins` is `active`.
The results from `sudo ufw status` for port 8080 is `ALLOW`. On AWS, the EC2 inbound rules  inclues port 8080 TCP 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0. So it appears that port 8080 is good. Checking for port use, `netstat -nlp | grep 8080` resulted in `tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN      -`. I killed the process and restarted nginx, gunicorn, and jenkins. Same results: the domain with port 8080 cannot connect but the doman goes to the Unlock Jenkins page.

I did look up other help pages, such as [the reverse proxy page from Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/), but I'm not sure how to integrate that into my current setup. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` file is as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 3.131.27.142;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
}
}

server {
server_name theafricankinshipreunion.com www.theafricankinshipreunion.com;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
}

location / {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    # proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 https://theafricankinshipreunion.com;
}

# SSL Configuration
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/theafricankinshipreunion.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/theafricankinshipreunion.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
error_log             /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;


}

# skipped lines show similar blocks for other domains

server {
if ($host = www.theafricankinshipreunion.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = theafricankinshipreunion.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name theafricankinshipreunion.com www.theafricankinshipreunion.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

And my `/etc/default/jenkins` file is as follows (with the last line added because of the instructions from DigitalOcean:

```
# defaults for Jenkins automation server

# pulled in from the init script; makes things easier.
NAME=jenkins

# arguments to pass to java

# Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"

# make jenkins listen on IPv4 address
#JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid

# user and group to be invoked as (default to jenkins)
JENKINS_USER=$NAME
JENKINS_GROUP=$NAME

# location of the jenkins war file
JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/$NAME/$NAME.war

# jenkins home location
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/$NAME

# set this to false if you don't want Jenkins to run by itself
# in this set up, you are expected to provide a servlet container
# to host jenkins.
RUN_STANDALONE=true

# log location.  this may be a syslog facility.priority
JENKINS_LOG=/var/log/$NAME/$NAME.log
#JENKINS_LOG=daemon.info

# Whether to enable web access logging or not.
# Set to "yes" to enable logging to /var/log/$NAME/access_log
JENKINS_ENABLE_ACCESS_LOG="no"

# OS LIMITS SETUP
#   comment this out to observe /etc/security/limits.conf
#   this is on by default because http://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/2fb288474e980d0e7ff9c4a3b768874835a3e92e
#   reported that Ubuntu's PAM configuration doesn't include pam_limits.so, and as a result the # of file
#   descriptors are forced to 1024 regardless of /etc/security/limits.conf
MAXOPENFILES=8192

# set the umask to control permission bits of files that Jenkins creates.
#   027 makes files read-only for group and inaccessible for others, which some security sensitive users
#   might consider benefitial, especially if Jenkins runs in a box that's used for multiple purposes.
#   Beware that 027 permission would interfere with sudo scripts that run on the master (JENKINS-25065.)
#
#   Note also that the particularly sensitive part of $JENKINS_HOME (such as credentials) are always
#   written without 'others' access. So the umask values only affect job configuration, build records,
#   that sort of things.
#
#   If commented out, the value from the OS is inherited,  which is normally 022 (as of Ubuntu 12.04,
#   by default umask comes from pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs

# UMASK=027

# port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
HTTP_PORT=8080


# servlet context, important if you want to use apache proxying
PREFIX=/$NAME

# arguments to pass to jenkins.
# --javahome=$JAVA_HOME
# --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST (default 0.0.0.0)
# --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT (default 8080; disable with -1)
# --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT
# --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password]
# --argumentsRealm.roles.$ADMIN_USER=admin
# --webroot=~/.jenkins/war
# --prefix=$PREFIX

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: I did a reinstall and followed the firewall-cmd commands on https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/. Now my whole site is down, and I can't figure out why. Changing my nginx sites-available/myproject files back to pre-jenkins does not restore my site. Restarting EC2 instance also does not restore my site. I can't figure out what step in my jenkins install attempt killed my whole site.

Comment: It turns out that my site is up using [the IP address](http://3.131.27.142/) but it doesn't work using the domain name. I have no idea what one has to do with the other. Or what either has to do with AWS Pipeline and CodeDeploy that pointed me in the direction of jenkins in the first place. It looks like this issue is way beyond my original question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to change the port while running jenkins

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

If you want to use https use the following command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=9090
```

Comment: I tried `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090` and I get `Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war`. After doing a search for jenkins.war, I find that I don't have a directory called `/usr/lib/jenkins`.

Comment: Hi @LaKisha David are you  using jenkins.war ? To run Jenkins them you can pass the above command to change port

Comment: I used the install instructions for linux as per [the jenkins instructions for linux](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/). Using that method, jenkins.war is not accessible by `jar -jar jenkins.war`. At this point, my once functioning website is now down, and I need to start a fresh EC2 instance with a fresh install of Nginx, Gunicorn, and Django because my efforts to reconfigure these to pre jenkins attempt has failed. I need to rebuild my site and use git branching before trying with jenkins again.